# org-mode capture click event within org-babel code block

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I wish to run C-c C-c, then click any code line to trigger my code (print "clicked" in this demo)

```
#+BEGIN_SRC elisp :results output
(defun myclick(n)
  (interactive "p")
  (print "clicked")
  )

(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
             '(lambda ()
                (local-set-key (kbd "<mouse-1>") #'myclick)))

#+END_SRC
```

But it doesn't print out anything now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-c C-c` evaluates the code which adds the function to the hook, but the hook is not run: you need to close the file and reopen it in order for the hook to run. Or you can add this to the code block:

```
(run-hooks 'org-mode-hook)
```

That will run the hook, which will do the `local-set-key` to set the mouse click to your function.